# RNCryptor iOS PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unsupported schema version 211'

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, encryption, rncryptor

Can't find much documentation on this error...I think it has to do with clashing versions of RNCryptor...the RNCryptor version from iOS is clashing with my server-side RNCryptor-php version...I think.

Here is all the output from the error:

`[Wed Dec 17 16:56:00 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unsupported schema version 211' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/lib/RNCryptor/Cryptor.php:70\nStack trace:\n#0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/lib/RNCryptor/Decryptor.php(66): RNCryptor\\Cryptor->_configureSettings(211)\n#1 /Library/WebServer/Documents/lib/RNCryptor/Decryptor.php(49): RNCryptor\\Decryptor->_parseHeaders('\\xD3}5\\xEBN\\xFB\\xD1\\xDD\\xBA\\xF5\\xD6\\xF6s\\xB7:...')\n#2 /Library/WebServer/Documents/lib/RNCryptor/Decryptor.php(22): RNCryptor\\Decryptor->_unpackEncryptedBase64Data('<03016077 0d269...')\n#3 /Library/WebServer/Documents/accessy/index.php(120): RNCryptor\\Decryptor->decrypt('<03016077 0d269...', 'AwEOM//0tNskVvC...')\n#4 /Library/WebServer/Documents/accessy/index.php(189): Auth->auth('AwEOM//0tNskVvC...', false)\n#5 {main}\n  thrown in /Library/WebServer/Documents/lib/RNCryptor/Cryptor.php on line 70`

I'm hoping someone can look at that and just tell me whats wrong. I have tried v2.0 and v2.1 on the iOS side and it looks like there is only one version for RNCryptor-php...I guess I could try v1.0/etc. but I'm guessing those versions are inherently less secure being that they are older. Anyone have any ideas?

This is my iOS encryption code that RNCryptor-php seems to not be able to handle for some reason:

```
NSData *what1 = [emailcurrent dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError *errory5;

NSData *useremaily = [RNEncryptor encryptData:what1 withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings password:@"xxxxx" error:&errory5];`
```

I'm still not sure about one thing actually, I have tried a few different things...but as of right now...I am sending `useremaily` along with the request (not converting it to a string or anything) as the `POST` data...I think this is correct.

Then I use NSURLConnection in the way I think I should be, and the connection happens and executes but I always get the above error in the PHP error log.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Wow - so it took me the past few days...all the way up until the point that I decided to include the NSURLConnection code in my question. This is what it was:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@", useremaily];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://192.168.1.10/accessy/index.php"]]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];`
```

The line that I think was messing everything up was:

`NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];`

I changed it to:

`NSData *postData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:post options:0];`

It actually still isn't working how I want it to...but this resolved that error incase anyone has this problem specifically. Might have to ask another question for what I'm dealing with now...but I guess if you want to comment about the process in general (iOS to PHP with RNCryptor) - that might still be helpful. Thanks.